# Flutter Desktop scrolling with mouse wheel: step size

Tags: windows, flutter, macos, dart, flutter-desktop

How do i change how much a single mouse scroll wheel step scrolls in a Flutter Desktop App (Windows, macOS, Linux), without affecting touchpad scrolling speed?

The default scroll wheel step size is too small, especially on 4K monitors.

If i multiply the step size through scroll listener, it breaks touchpad scrolling, makes it too fast.

I maybe need to somehow distinguish between touchpad scroll and mousewheel scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no reliable way to distinguish between scroll wheel scroll and trackpad scroll because they are the same event at the engine level. Because [trackpad gestures aren't directly supported yet](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23604) trackpad scroll is currently implemented as a series of discrete incremental scroll events rather than a gesture.

Once that issue is addressed, they will be different types of scrolling that can be distinguished from each other.